# shell: return values of test on file/directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not able to check the return values of the function test; man test didn't help me much.

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(test -d $1)
if [ $test -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "the file exists and is a directory"
elif [ $test -eq 0 ]
    echo "file does not exist or is not a directory"
else 
    echo "error"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(test -d $1) is going to be substituted with what test outputs, not its return code. If you want to check its return code, use `$?`, e.g.

> ```
> test -d $1
> test=$?
> if [ $test -eq 1 ]
> ...
> ```

Comment: No.  Don't do that.  Just do 'if test -d $1; then ... else...; fi'.  Or, even 'test -d $1 && ...'

Comment: Well yes, for test you wouldn't check $? since the point of it is just to return 0/1. But the general case is to use $? for programs that have many return values.

Answer (score 5):

Try, instead

```
if test -d $1
then
    echo 'the file exists and is a directory'
else
    echo 'the file doesn't exist or is not a directory'
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Every time you use `test` on the return code of `test`, God kills a kitten.

```
if test -d "$1"
```

or

```
if [ -d "$1" ]
```

Comment: sorry Ignacio... poor kittens :p

Comment: @nour: In other words: `[` **is** `test` (both are Bash builtins as well as external programs (`/usr/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/test`).

Comment: This uses the bash built-in and is therefor probably negligibly faster. Though it goes about the testing in much the same way as @Steve Emmerson's solution. I prefer this method.